# Changing illegal copy of Windows 10 to a clean copy

Tags: windows, windows-10, reinstall

I acquired an illegal copy of Windows 10 1809-1903 Enterprise through a friend who got it for me. I was wondering if there were any ways to install a clean copy of Windows without the Enterprise coming back? I also tried to install a clean copy I got from the illegal copy on another computer and it comes up with the illegal copy on that computer. Really need some advice because I can't afford a brand new copy of Windows 10

Comment: You won't get help with piracy on this site.

Comment: **Changing illegal copy of Windows 10 to a clean copy:** You can achieve this in merely 3 steps. 1) Go to Microsoft's site or Amazon. 2) Buy a license. 3) Enter the key. **I can't afford a brand new copy of Windows 10:** Opt for some alternatives then such as Linux.

Comment: I'm not looking to pirate anything....I'm looking to install a  perfectly clean copy and not use this pirated copy

Comment: Windows 10 will actually run, and run ok, without a license. Just do a clean install and don't enter a license key. There's no telling when Microsoft will end this, but so far they haven't.

Answer (score 1):

Go to this [Microsoft web page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), download the "MediaCreationTool" and follow the intructions:

> 1. Select "MediaCreationTool", and select Run. You need to be an administrator
>      to run this tool.
> 2. On the License terms page, if you accept the license terms, select Accept.
> 3. On the What do you want to do? page, select Create installation media for another PC, and then select Next.
> 4. Select the language, edition, and architecture (64-bit or 32-bit) for Windows 10.
> 5. Select which media you want to use:
>
>    - USB flash drive. Attach a blank USB flash drive with at least 8GB of space. Any content on the flash drive will be deleted.
>    - ISO file. Save an ISO file to your PC, which you can use to create a DVD. After the file is downloaded, you can go to location where the file is saved, or select Open DVD burner, and follow the instructions to burn the file to a DVD.

After the installation media is created, use it to install a fresh copy of Windows 10 on your PC. After you’ve installed Windows 10 without a key, it won’t actually be activated. However, an unactivated version of Windows 10 doesn’t have many restrictions. With Windows XP, Microsoft actually used Windows Genuine Advantage (WGA) to disable access to your computer. These days, Windows just complains at you in a few minor, cosmetic ways.

Initially, you won’t notice a difference. Eventually, Windows will start nagging you a tiny bit. First, you’ll notice a watermark in the bottom-right corner of your screen. You’ll also see a “Windows isn’t activated. Activate Windows now.” link at the bottom of the Settings app. This is the only form of nag you’ll see–there are no pop-up windows, for example. More details [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/244678/you-dont-need-a-product-key-to-install-and-use-windows-10/).

When You save enough money to buy a valid Windows 10 product key, do that, and register your Copy of Windows 10.

Comment: Thnx I'll try and see if it work